# HTML PHP string special character escape

Tags: php, escaping

Just wondering if it is possible to write link button using PHP with so many special characters in the string.

```
  $link='index.php?topic=transactions&content=transaction_adjustment&tx_number='.$tx_number;
  echo '<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href="'.$link.'"">Adjust</button>';
```

Comment: Nothing overly special, yet [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) + [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) + [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) shouldn't be discounted.

Comment: You just have an extra `"` here `'.$link.'"">`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 $link='index.php?topic=transactions&content=transaction_adjustment&tx_number='.$tx_number;
 echo '<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href=\''.$link.'\'">Adjust</button>';
```